# Centos 7 - Trying to install postgresql (from postgresql.org)

Tags: centos, postgresql

I am trying to install Socorro service on fresh Centos 7 (installed on Amazon ec2). I am following the instructions from the official documentation - [Socorro](http://socorro.readthedocs.org/en/latest/production-install.html). I installed the PostgreSQL 9.3 RPM packages from yum.postgresql.org. Now I run into two problems:

1 - When I run this command

```
$ sudo service postgresql-9.3 initdb
```

I am getting following message -

```
The service command supports only basic LSB actions (start, stop, restart, try-restart, reload, force-reload, status). For other actions, please try to use systemctl.
```

2 - When I run this command:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart postgresql-9.3
```

the message is:

```
Job for postgresql-9.3.service failed. See 'systemctl status postgresql-9.3.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

I am following the steps from the instruction, and I haven't installed anything else. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: /usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/postgresql93-setup initdb and then systemctl start postgresql-9.3 ?

Comment: The first command gives this message: **Initializing database ... mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data//pg_log’: File exists** and the second is giving the same message as from above. This is from the pg_log:
initdb: directory "/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data" exists but is not empty
If you want to create a new database system, either remove or empty
the directory "/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data" or run initdb
with an argument other than "/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data".

Comment: mv /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/pg_log /var/lib/pgsql/data/9.3/pg_log.old and again ?

Comment: Still the same message.

Comment: You can rename your data dir and check owner of /var/lib/pgsql/ it sounds like permission problem the entired dir and subdirs should be postgers:postgres.

Comment: @Sasha: Still the same like "file exists", or still cannot start the pgsql service? / Just curious: Why don't you install pgsql from the official CentOS repos? Do you *need* 9.3 instead of 9.2?

Answer (score 1):

Try this command `/usr/lib/pgsql-9.3/bin/postgresql93-setup initdb`

Answer (score 1):

```
/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/postgresql93-setup initdb
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! When posting a command, please make sure to provide at least a short explanation of what it is and how it works.

Comment: this worked for me with centos-7 and postgresql-9.4